# Fitting image inside div with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one strange problem ( at least for me ). When I upload image and save to database then I show it on the page. The images are big `~10mb` and high resolution.

When I manually re-size the image to 500x500 they are fitted in the div and all is good. But if I didn't re-size them and try to load into the div they break all the divs. What I mean is this:

1. Image manually re-sized to 500x500
   [image]
2. Images not re-sized and loaded into gallery with their dimensions.
   [image]

This is the HTML and CSS of that part of page

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6">
      <div class="g-item">
         <img src="" alt="">
            <a data-rel="lightbox" class="overlay" href="">
                <span>+</span>
            </a>
      </div> <!-- /.g-item -->
   </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

and the css

```
.g-item {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 6px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
 }

.g-item img {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.g-item .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #d8aa46;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

If I try with `height..` it is cropping the image...

EDIT:

I've put `height` and `width` to `250px`. Then  `min-width: 100%;` and `min-height: 100%;` and this is the result. The image is not fitting.

```
.g-item {
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 6px;
position: relative;
background-color: white;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
backface-visibility: hidden;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;    
}

.g-item img {
overflow: hidden;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding `height:auto` to `.g-item img` ?

Comment: Yes, and no change it is still like second image..

Comment: Do you want them to be square (and cropped)?

Comment: I want them like on the first image but without to manually re-size them so yes .. I trying to make them square and fit in the dimensions of the div

Comment: Ah---gotchya from your comment to my answer--I removed it as it does not solve the problem. You may need some javascript to solve the problem...I'm not sure if it's possible to determine the aspect ratio of the images without it.

Comment: Your page is screaming for an image formatting library such as imagick to create formatted thumbnails that won't decimate broadband connections.  Long ago I did a wedding photographer's site using script from galleryproject.org that gave her a gui to upload and manage her (many) photos, and I used it to resize, thumbnail, and store a list of the photos in each gallery, then pulled them from the DBn for her website and displayed in my own UI for the public facing website.  A lazy developer is a good developer......

Comment: But why is happen this only on high resolution images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1 (no Bootstrap)

---

## HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6">
      <div class="g-item" style="background-image:url('your-image-url');">

            <a data-rel="lightbox" class="overlay" href="">
                <span>+</span>
            </a>
      </div> <!-- /.g-item -->
   </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

## CSS

```
.g-item{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

### Option 2 (with Bootstrap)

Warning! This wil crop images in portrait orientation.

---

## HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6">
      <div class="g-item"">
            <img clas="img-responsive" src="" alt="">
            <a data-rel="lightbox" class="overlay" href="">
                <span>+</span>
            </a>
      </div> <!-- /.g-item -->
   </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

## CSS

```
.g-item{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but still cropping the images. The problem is on height. It doesn't matter what size/resolution is image it is cropped only on height.

Comment: On the first image in my question the image dimensions are 500x500 and gallery aquares are 250x250 and they fit perfectly there for my needs.

Comment: It is impossible to fit a rectangular shape in a square, and have it fill the entire square, without cropping. Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: I have image with dimension `2203x3799` when I crop it via php-library `PHP Image Magician` to `500x500` it fit perfectly into this square which is 250x250. But if it didn't re-sized it didn't fir. Maybe I can't understood something here.

Comment: If you don't resize it, then your are trying to fit a rectangular image (2203x37799) in to a square. Witch will always result in a cropped image. You can try to set the image height to 100% and the with to "auto" but then you'll have the same problem with images in portrait orientation.

Comment: So to be clear if I want to fit rectangular image into square div I must resize the image or it can happen? Is it because of the bootstrap or is just how the css work?

Comment: IF I UNDERSTAND YOU RIGHT: Than it is just the way life works. You kant fit a beam in a square hole.